# Stop or continue execution of a loop based on variable value

Tags: c#

I've different thread which contains an infinite loop, inside each loop I call this method that return a `true` or `false` based on specific condition, but I'm going to return true just for example:

```
public void Test()
{
    return true;
}
```

I'm wondering if can I break or continue the execution of the loop in a quick way, I mean, without write in any loop this condition:

```
if(Test())
{
    break;
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `break`.  `continue skips the rest of the loop and immediately starts the next iteration of the loop.  `break` will exit the loop and execute the next line after the loop (if any)

Comment: of yes, I changed the example, sorry, too many hours on pc..

Comment: Use a while loop and have the condition be the return value of the `Test()` method?  You have not provided nearly enough detail.

Comment: Does C# not have a `break` argument for the type of method being broken? Like in vb.net there's `exit for` or `exit try` or `exit sub` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I catch your meaning, you probably want to `do` the work `while` `Test()` is not returning false:

```
do 
{
    //your stuff
} while (Test());
```

Or if you won't necessarily iterate even once:

```
while(Test())
{
    //your stuff
}
```